# ftell returns 11 instead of 10

Tags: c, file-pointer

I have a file `test.txt`, which contains two lines.

```
123456789
abcdefghi
```

And here is a C code.

```c
FILE* fp;
char str[20];
fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
printf("%d", ftell(fp));                       // 0
printf("%s", fgets(str, sizeof(str), fp));     // 123456789\n
printf("%d", ftell(fp));                       // 11
```

I was confused why there are 10 characters(`"123456789\n"`) in the line, but the position increases by 11.

[edited]

Thank to the comments. But I didn't know how to update what I have clarified in correct format. I note what I did wrong in this question here.
 1. In Windows, `'\n'` is stored as `"\r\n"`, so it returns 11 instead.
 2. `fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")` this will convert `"\r\n"` back to `'\n'`. Open the file in binary, `"rb"` and `fgets` should read `"123456789\r\n"`.
 3. I have to use `%ld` in format string since the return type of `ftell` is `long int`.

Comment: Why is this tagged "c++"?

Comment: Probably you are running this program on windows, where newlines are encoded as two characters: "\r\n", which are then converted to "\n" as specified by the C standard.

Comment: Aside: `printf("%d", ftell(fp));` is sending a `long` value to the `int` specifier `%d`, which is *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I did this on Windows. @xing, do you mean `str` is `"123456789\n"` instead of `"123456789\r\n"` when I "take it out" from the file? Now I have another question, can I do something to let the code can run on both Windows and other OS? Thanks!

Comment: Why won't the code run on other OS? And why do you need this program?

Comment: Sorry for asking a unclear question. I want to ask, does this difference(different position) between OSes cause some problem in compatibility? If yes, is there any method to fix this problem?

Comment: @anonymous If there's something wrong with your question, then edit the question.

Comment: is it a big problem to read the content and see? It would take less than to ask this question.

Comment: either a) open the files in "b"inary mode and be prepared to handle the line endings yourself or b) open the files in text mode and with text files **never use `ftell` for any other purpose than to save a location in the stream that you can `fseek` to**.